# Understanding Copy command

Tags: rhel, cp

I have one copy `cp` command related question:
In my home directory, there is a folder which is known as `WebDev`, Inside `WebDev` folder, there is a `target` folder which contains `WebDev.rar`.

Now, I am deploying the new war file after building using maven. My tomcat is in different directory. So basically, when I am inside the tomcat directory, I am typing the following command:

•  `sudo cp ~/WebDev/target/WebDev.war .`

Basically what above command is doing is (since I am already inside the tomcat directory), I am copying the `WebDev.rar`inside the tomcat. Is it a correct way to do that? I didn't understand why there is a dot `.` with a space after `WebDev.rar`.

Or alternatively, if I want to copy the file by navigating to various directory using FileZilla, is that a good option?

Comment: `.` is the current directory you are in (and `..` the parent directory of that)

Comment: @thrig Thanks. And the dot `.` should always be after one space, right? In my case `WebDev.war` and one space and then `.`.

Comment: `cp` requires two arguments, and the space delimits the source and the destination arguments.

Comment: Okay, so in my case `~/WebDev/target/WebDev.war` is the source and `.` is the destination separated by space which makes sense. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following commands are equivalent:

```
cp ~/WebDev/target/WebDev.war .
cp ~/WebDev/target/WebDev.war ./
cp ~/WebDev/target/WebDev.war ./WebDev.war
cp ~/WebDev/target/WebDev.war WebDev.war
```